# Functional derivative and entropy

Tags: metric-tensor, entropy, functional-derivatives

I just started to read about (entanglement) entropy for CFTs. I have a confusion that probably originates from a misunderstanding about functional derivatives.
For instance, in (4.21) in [this review](https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-th/0605073.pdf) they want to understand how the entanglement entropy varies with x. Let $\ell = \Delta x$ and $S$ be the entropy. They write
\begin{equation}
\ell \frac{d}{d \ell} S(x) = \int d^dx \delta g_{\mu \nu}(x) \frac{\delta}{\delta g_{\mu \nu}(x)} S(x)
\end{equation}
They seem to have replaced $d$ with $\delta$. So that the RHS is perhaps more generally $\delta \ell \frac{\delta}{\delta \ell}$? The RHS in the first equation looks like $\delta S(x)$ to me and I am already confused how $\delta S(x) = \delta \ell \frac{\delta}{\delta \ell}$.

But putting that a side for a moment. Why is it that $\ell$ is being varied on the LHS and the metric being varied on the RHS of the first equation? Why is it obvious that it should be $\delta g_{\mu \nu}(x)$ and not $\delta \ell$ inside the integral?

Comment: Your equation looks weird - $x$ appears on the LHS but is integrated over on the RHS. Do you mean $\int d^dy \delta g_{\mu\nu}(y)\frac{\delta}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}(y)}S(x)$ on the RHS?

Comment: I agree @Mike. It is confusing. $x$ is the only scale in their theory and seems to appear as I wrote it. It could be that only $\Delta x$ is what survives in the LHS, because we know entanglement entropy in 2d CFT depends on $\Delta x$.